# rsync over ssh results in 0 files, but no error message

Tags: terminal, syntax, rsync

I'm trying to rsync a large directory of around 200 GB from a server to my local external hard drive. I can ssh onto the server and see the directory fine. I can also cd into the external hard drive fine. When I try and rsync the file across, I don't get an error, but the last line of the rsync output is 'total size is 0 speedup is 0.00', and there are no files in the destination directory.

Here's how I ssh onto the server successfully:

```
ssh skgtmdf@live.rd.ucl.ac.uk
```

Here's my rsync command:

```
rsync -avrt -progress -e "ssh skgtmdf@live.rd.ucl.ac.uk:/mnt/gpfs/live/rd01__/ritd-ag-project-rd012x-smmca23/" "/Volumes/DUAL DRIVE/ONP/2022.08.10_results/"
```

And here's the rsync output:

```
sending incremental file list
drwxrwxrwx         65,536 2022/08/10 21:32:06 .

sent 57 bytes  received 64 bytes  242.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it quoted, the source path is part of the remote shell option (`-e` value) rather than a separate argument as it should be.

```
rsync -avrt -progress -e "ssh skgtmdf@live.rd.ucl.ac.uk:/mnt/gpfs/live/rd01__/ritd-ag-project-rd012x-smmca23/" "/Volumes/DUAL DRIVE/ONP/2022.08.10_results/"
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                          This is all part of the `-e` option value
```

This means `rsync` doesn't see that as a sync source at all, but just part of the command it'll use to connect to the remote system. I'm not sure why this doesn't lead to an error. In any case, the fix is simple: don't include `ssh` with the source path.

As I noticed later (see comments) the `--progress` option needs a double-dash or it'll be wildly misparsed. Fixing both of these things gives:

```
rsync -avrt --progress -e ssh "skgtmdf@live.rd.ucl.ac.uk:/mnt/gpfs/live/rd01__/ritd-ag-project-rd012x-smmca23/" "/Volumes/DUAL DRIVE/ONP/2022.08.10_results/"
```

In fact, since `ssh` is the default command for making a remote connection, you can leave off `-e ssh` entirely:

```
rsync -avrt --progress "skgtmdf@live.rd.ucl.ac.uk:/mnt/gpfs/live/rd01__/ritd-ag-project-rd012x-smmca23/" "/Volumes/DUAL DRIVE/ONP/2022.08.10_results/"
```

Comment: In fact, your first command works, but the second one (without ssh) doesn't. I get this error: rsync: [Receiver] Failed to exec ss: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [Receiver=3.2.4]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(228) [Receiver=3.2.4]

Comment: @Mike D'oh! the `--progress` option needs a double-dash, or else it'll be interpreted as a series of single-letter options: `-p -r -o -g -r -e ss`, and the final `-e ss` is making it try to run `ss` instead of `ssh` as the remote shell command. Double the dash, and it should start working.

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -azve ssh user@host:/src/ target/
```

Normally, you don't need to wrap -e flag with ". It's probably messing the connection string